# How to import JSON and convert it to appropriate data frame

Tags: r, json, dataframe, flatten

My json is

```
{  
   "Gunho":{  
      "status":"Babo",
      "title":"CTO"
   },
   "Adrian":{  
      "status":"Babo2",
      "title":"BD"
   }
}
```

I want my data frame to have column names =`'status'`, `'title'`, row names = `'Gunho'`, `'Adrian'` with assigned values.

I used `stream_in` to import json file and `flatten` function to make a dataframe but couldn't convert it to the way I wanted

Comment: You can use as.data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `jsonlite` library? Here's a good tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/new-package-jsonlite-a-smarter-json-encoderdecoder/

The `read_json()` command from the library has a vector simplification option that might be helpful.